# What material provides semi-permanent, strong bonding with a concrete floor?

Tags: repair, concrete

The professionals doing repairs at a workplace seem to be capable of patching  stairs with material so tough, and make it stick to the existing cement with such strength, that the patching survives years of use, even when it is done on the tip of a stair, as shown below.

[image: staircase]

My own needs are far more modest. Still, I'd like this not to be a job that looks bad after six months, and that gets completely detached after twelve. My garage floor is abraded in a few places. No place is worse than the one letting air through under the garage door.

[image: garage floor]

I know that I could use some cement, but that will not last very long. Can you guess what material has been used on the stairs above, or can you suggest some material that will provide a semi-permanent solution? I am quite happy using an entirely different color (I'll paint with an epoxy-based paint at some point anyway), just so long as it lasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PC-Concrete is a brand I have used especially if you are going to paint over it.
It is a good idea to acid wash the area (10% muriatic and water) then rinse.
Once dry fill the area and let cure. Remember if you use Acid to add the acid to water.

Comment: Some formulations of PC-Concrete appear to include epoxy. That would explain the fantastic adhesion in the stairs pictured. It would also mean that ventilation must be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your situation:
http://www.quikrete.com/AtHome/Video-Thin-Repairs.asp